# Intellij IDEA insert variable names in methods

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA 13 for android development.

Some methods has long list of parameters. For example, db.query(...) and I can't remember the order of them.

Is there any plugin or can i change some settings to make IDEA insert variables from function template?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will show a lit of the parameters, with the current one bolded. As long as you have either the source or javadoc for the library (or JDK/SDK) attached to the corresponding definition, you will see the parameters' names.

If you invoke code completion while entering parameters, IDEA will show at the top only ones that are of the correct type. Furthermore, if one of you local variables is the same name (or similar to) the required parameter's name, it will be at the top of the list. So if there is a method that takes an `int` named 'width', and I have several int variables, but one is named 'theWidth', it would be at the top. (Again, this assumes you have javadoc or source attached so IDEA can determine parameter names.) If IDEA can find local variables that satisfy all parameters (or all the first x parameters) of the method, there will be an option in the code completion list to complete all of them, The icon will be a double circle. The below screen shot shows how the `HttpServletReqest` is at the top of the list. So I do not have to remember if the parameter order is "request, response" or "response, "request". Notice the fourth option is to complete both the request and the response.

[image]